# Get sorted by field items from DynamoDB in Serverless App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I have a function in Serverless project to get all items from Amazon DynamoDB Table:

```
'use strict';

 var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
 var doc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
 var api = {};

 api.getItems = (event, context, callback) {
    var id = event.pathParameters.id;

    var params = {
        TableName: 'Items',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':itemId': id }
    };

    doc.scan(params, function(err, res) {
            if (err) return cb(null, {
                statusCode: err.statusCode,
                headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ err: err.message })
            });

            if (res.Items === undefined) {
                return cb(null, {
                    statusCode: 404,
                    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ err: "Assigned order are not found" })
                });
            }

            if (res.Items.length > 0) {
                return cb(null, {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                    body: JSON.stringify(res.Items)
                });
            } else {
                return cb(null, {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" },
                    body: JSON.stringify([])
                });

            }
        }

    };

    module.exports = api;
```

Each of response items contains `date` field. 
How can I get sorted items (in asc/desc) by this field, using the query/scan from DynamoDB?

Comment: can you please describe your hash/range table keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way DynamoDB will return ordered results is if your table has a sort key.

If you wanted to query on an id, and order by date, you could use id as your partition key and a 'date as number' attribute as your sort key. DynamoDB keys can only be [String,Number or Binary attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_KeySchemaElement.html). You could have an attribute that was a number and represented the date in YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format, which would naturally sort in the correct order. You could then use DynamoDB ScanIndexForward function and limit your result set to a given number of items.

Alternatively you could just query by id and sort by date using application code.